# Время работы функции в STL

Tags: c++, stl, очередь, асимптотика

Какое асимптотическое время работы функции `q.size()` очереди приоритетов?

Comment: О(1) вроде бы. Там же куча по сути.

Comment: [std::priority_queue::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/size): Complexity - Constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для всех стандартных контейнеров `size()` выполняется за константное время.

Comment: ну спорное утверждение. для списка например.

Comment: привет из очереди проверок. ответообразное, а вот верность/неверность оценивать не буду.

Comment: @pavel Тут https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size четко пишут, что O(1). Я говорю только о стандартных контейнерах, не самопальных.

Comment: @Mikhailo даже по этой ссылке написано "Constant or linear. (until C++11)". А gcc ради бинарной совместимости оставили линейную и дальше (не точно).

Comment: @pavel Там четко написано, что начиная с С++11 - константная. Сейчас уже С++17 действующий... Мы разговариваем о современном С++ или о том, который был в прошлом тысячелетии? Это уже пустопоорожний треп и хорошая мина при плохой игре - что если какой-то контейнер оставил линейную... (при том что реально она легко делается константной). Вы же не будете рассказывать, например, что некий дорожный знак в 1970-е годы означал нечто иное, и на этом основании дезавуировать нынешние ПДД?